# Is there a way to scatter objects with its animation with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So, I'm making a crowd generator, and I've set up the scattering already, but I cannot get the base object's animation to get played on the scattered ones. So the base one's animation is playing, but the scattered people are static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

of course you can.

Just use instance on points with e.g. collection like this:

[image]

In the collection the objets should be animated.

Press play and enjoy the show.

[image]

you can e.g. import mixamo animations+characters, just move the rigged mesh (not the armature) in the collection...and you got:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm :D

Comment: you are welcome